# How To Fix a PCB

Tags: pcb, components

While I was welding the components to the PCB, I have burnt some of the trace and few of the green areas. I have read that using a pencil to re-draw the tracing is useful. Is there any other way that I will guarantee it will work.

Comment: Would you consider re-writing this using the normal rules of writing in English? Like not capitalizing every word.

Comment: @ThePhoton: P4P doesn't do this [elsewhere](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60702/why-is-the-probability-zero-for-any-given-value-of-a-normal-distribution) - boredom does strange things to some people.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I am not bored. But writing every word with capital gives to it a nice shape

Comment: @ThePhoton No Problem.

Comment: Nice shapes do not equal good readability. Also, are you *welding* or *soldering*? If you're welding, then that's your problem...

Comment: Given that the entire world's first language isn't English and welding and soldering sound pretty much the same in, say, Spanish  and given the low chance that anyone would be welding to a pcb, I think the hostility is unwarranted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "the green areas" I assume you mean the solder mask. Don't worry about that as it won't affect the electrical functioning of the PCB. If you've lost a trace or two, it's annoying but an inevitable fact of prototyping.

You can sometimes use a silver paint to repair small tracks but it can be expensive. Just use some light wire to bridge the gaps. There's enamelled wire, like that used for wound radio antennas which will work if you scrape off the insulation. An then there is wire that's called "enamelled" wire but the insulation isn't enamel, it's polyurethane. The insulation will just burn off and, after tinning the ends, you can use that to patch from point to point.

If you posted a picture of the damage I'm sure we could help more.

Edit: I'll add a picture of one I did on a prototype PCB. The chip right in the middle there is a tiny 32kHz clock chip. I'd gotten the pins back to front and had to solder it in upside down (called "dead bugging"). The wire you see is just light wire from the pins to the tracks.

[image]

Comment: Thank You A lot For Your Help. I will Try To Post a Picture Of The Damage

Comment: You can often scrounge fine uncounted wire for such repairs from larger stranded cables - it may take some looking as the gauge of the strands varies all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

First, don't weld to a PCB.  Second, those boards are toast.  Perhaps you can recover them with some work, but depending on the circuit the now partially-conductive charred areas could cause problems.

Get more boards made, and this time don't abuse them by welding.